# T Entity does no contain a definition for id

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am following [this](https://codingblast.com/entity-framework-core-generic-repository/) tutorial in order to understand better generic repositories.

GetById method :

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
{
   return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
               .AsNoTracking()
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

But i get this error: TEntity does not contain a definition for id.

Is it here something that I am missing or what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am using ASP.NET Core 2

Comment: I think you are missing IEntity reference: https://github.com/Ibro/GenericRepositorySimple/blob/master/GenericRepository/Data/IEntity.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial has a type constraint on the generic argument

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity {
    //...
}
```

this assumes that an `IEntity` interface with an `Id` property, which was not shown in the article, but exists in the source code linked to in the article.

```
public interface IEntity {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

That means the all the entities used with the generic repository need to be derived from that interface for it to work.